# Position element, but no space left

Tags: html, css, position

I have simple problem. I need to put content to div (width is set), but there isn't space, so browser put it on next line.

Problem is visualized here -> http://jsfiddle.net/QtAQa/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="heading">Name:</div>
    <div class="data">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="error">Enter your name, please</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
    width: 600px;
}
.row div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.heading {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
.data {
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

It would be great to somehow put the div.error next to input, but there isn't space left.

I don't want to use position: absolute or position: relative, because I don't know how wide will div.data be.

Can I be done only with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
.row {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: visible;
    position:relative
}
.row div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.heading {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
.data {
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}
.error {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -60px;
    top:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QtAQa/5/

Answer (score 4):

You `row` is simply to short:

```
.row {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Expand that container and the error container will fit.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/jFSGP/)

An alternative would be using this to force the browser not to break spaces:

```
.row {
    width: 600px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/ea73g/)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, because that box needs to be that wide.

Comment: @Forex Then you can use the alternative with `white-space: nowrap;` where you don't need to update the width of the container.